# Does `va_end()` need to be invoked before each `return` statement in a variadic function with multiple `return` statements?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, c-standard-library

There is one thing that always puzzles me about `va_end()`. I often read that is not an actual function, but a preprocessor macro. Although this might sound like an insignificant detail, it could actually influence where `va_end()` needs to be invoked.

The question simply is: Does `va_end()` need to be invoked before each `return` statement in a variadic function with multiple `return` statements?

The variadic function in the following example has the trivial task of returning the first non-`NULL` of its arguments. As you can see there are three `return` statements in the function body. One of them appears after `va_start()` but before `va_end()`.

Is this code correct?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static const void * const FIRST_NON_NULL_END = (void *) "";

void * first_non_null (
    const void * const ptr1,
    ...
) {

    if (ptr1) {

        return ptr1 == FIRST_NON_NULL_END ? NULL : (void *) ptr1;

    }

    void * retval;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, ptr1);

    do {

        retval = va_arg(args, void *);

        if (retval == FIRST_NON_NULL_END) {

            /*  Is this correct? Here I do not invoke `va_end()`!  */
            return NULL;

        }

    } while (!retval);

    va_end(args);
    return retval;

}

int main () {

    const char * const my_string = first_non_null(
        NULL,
        NULL,
        "autumn",
        NULL,
        "rose",
        FIRST_NON_NULL_END
    );

    printf("The first non-null value is: \"%s\".\n", my_string);

    return 0;

}
```

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, the example above was written in that form for didactic purposes only. In real life it can be rewritten in a much nicer and synthetic way as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static const void * const FIRST_NON_NULL_END = (void *) "";

void * first_non_null (
    const void * const ptr1,
    ...
) {

    const void * retval;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, ptr1);

    for (retval = ptr1; !retval; retval = va_arg(args, const void *))
        ;;

    va_end(args);
    return retval == FIRST_NON_NULL_END ? NULL : (void *) retval;

}

int main () {

    const char * const my_string = first_non_null(
        NULL,
        NULL,
        "autumn",
        NULL,
        "rose",
        FIRST_NON_NULL_END
    );

    printf("The first non-null value is: \"%s\".\n", my_string);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: [C11 7.16.1.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1.3): *"... if the `va_end` macro is not invoked before the return, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: The usual meaning of "invoked before" is with respect to execution order.  So you treat it just like a function that needs to be called.  Your code has UB.

Comment: Put another way: it should *always* be called, precisely once, during the lifetime of your function (that is, after its start and prior to its `return`).

Comment: Technically, the C standard allows `va_end` to be an honest function instead of a macro (C17 7.16.1p1), in which case the intended interpretation seems obvious.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would being a macro or not influence where it has to be called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C Standard (7.16.1 Variable argument list access macros)

> 1 ... Each invocation of the va_start and va_copy macros shall be matched
> by a corresponding invocation of the va_end macro in the same
> function.

So if `va_start` was used before any return statement and `va_end` was not yet invoked then it shall be invoked.

Comment: Hi Vlad, thank you for your answer. Although your interpretation does not totally convince me. One could translate the sentence “Each invocation of the va_start and va_copy macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the va_end macro in the same function” with: `va_start()` appears once, hence `va_end()` must appear only once within the function, independently of the number of `return` statements.

Comment: @madmurphy If the control is passed to a return statement and the previous code contained an invocation of va_start then you shall invoke va_end. Otherwise va_start will not be followed by va_end.

Comment: If `va_end()` is a preprocessor macro it will always be reached, the preprocessor knows nothing about `return` statements. That is why I ask.

Comment: @madmurphy The macro will be expanded but it does not mean that its code  will be executed. For example you can write a macro that inserts an expression with a function call. But it does not mean that the expression will be evaluated because the control can bypass the statement where the expression is present.

Comment: But that is the question. Does it actually contain *code*, or compiler-specific magic tricks?

Comment: @madmurphy Any so-called "trick" is a code.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.